# Почему возникает ошибка, при том в БД таблица создается в yii2

Tags: yii2, миграция

Не могу создать миграцию

```
   public function up() {
        $this->createTable('service_category2service', [
            'service_category_id' => $this->integer(11)->unsigned()->notNull(),
            'service_id'        => $this->integer(11)->unsigned()->notNull(),
        ]);

        $this->addForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SC2S_PARENT', 'service_category2service', ['service_category_id'], \app\models\Service::tableName(), ['service_id']);
        $this->addForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SC2S_SERVICE', 'service_category2service', ['service_id'], \app\models\Service::tableName(), ['service_id']);

        $this->createIndex('UK_SC2S', 'service_category2service', ['service_category_id', 'service_id'], true);
    }

    public function down() {
        $this->dropForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SC2S_PARENT','service_category2service');
        $this->dropForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SC2S_SERVICE','service_category2service');

        $this->dropTable(\app\models\ServiceCategory2service::tableName());
    }
```

Прикладываю миграцию для таблицы сервисов:

```
$this->createTable('services', [
        'service_id' => $this->primaryKey()->unsigned()->notNull(),
        'title'      => $this->string()->comment('название для списка услуг'),
        'url'        => $this->string(128)->notNull()->unique(),
        'icon'       => $this->string()->comment('картинка для списка услуг'),
        'bg_pic'     => $this->string(),

        'lead'      => $this->text()->comment('описание для списка услуг'),
        'lead_full' => $this->text()->comment('описание для списка услуг'),
        'body'      => $this->text(),

        'seo_title'       => $this->string(),
        'seo_description' => $this->text(),
        'seo_keywords'    => $this->text(),

        'sort'   => $this->smallInteger()->unsigned()->notNull(),

        // скрыта/опубликована
        'status' => $this->boolean()->unsigned()->notNull()->defaultValue(1),
      ]);
    }
```

Ошибка

```
foreign key FK_ITEM_SC2S_PARENT: service_category2service (service_category_id) references services (service_id) ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `service_category2service` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_SC2S_PARENT` FOREIGN KEY (`service_category_id`) REFERENCES `services` (`service_id`)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разные движки таблиц. MYISAM и INNODB, не было индекса в таблице services